# Organizando multiplos p-value no R (kruskal.test)

Tags: r

Utilizando o código abaixo, criei um data.frame() com 5 variáveis. Dessa forma, eu posso obter o valor de p utilizando a variável 'table' e kruskal.test().

```
> sample1 <- c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3)
> sample2 <- c(7, 7, 10, 6, 10)
> sample3 <- c(10, 13, 12, 14, 13)
> sample4 <- c(15, 20, 18, 20, 17)
> sample5 <- c(4, 5, 3, 3, 4)
>
> table <- data.frame(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4, sample5)
> 
> kruskal.test(table$sample1, table$sample2)$p.value
[1] 0.1353353
> kruskal.test(table$sample1, table$sample3)$p.value
[1] 0.2614641
> kruskal.test(table$sample1, table$sample4)$p.value
[1] 0.6822703
> kruskal.test(table$sample1, table$sample5)$p.value
[1] 0.4723666
```

Porém, gostaria de organizar o resultado em um dafa.frame() parecido com a imagem abaixo utilizando estritamente a variável ‘table’.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe algum pacote, comando ou alternativa para que isso aconteça. Já vi algo parecido com o uso na função cor() mas não consegui encontrar nada que se aplique aqui por enquanto.

Comment: você pode fazer isso com 2 `for`. eu não sei uma forma mais elegante de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

Obtive a resposta na versão international do fórum. Basta complementar com o código abaixo que a tabela será gerada...

```
pvals <- outer(table, table, function(x,y) {
  mapply(function(x,y) kruskal.test(x,y)$p.value, x,y)
})

diag(pvals) <- NA
pvals
```

Valeu pessoal....